# exclude key failure in ftp-deploy

Tags: git, github, networking, server, workflow

i'm using SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action to deploy my files to my server,

but the key 'exclude' doesn't actually exclude Workspace and my resources folders, it works fine for .git and .github folders.(i guess the problem is with exclude key's value syntax but i couldn't find the right one for my folder.)

 also i don't want to use .gitignore bc i want my resources folder in my repository.

```
name:  Deploy laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2

      - name:  Sync files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.FTP_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          exclude: .github** .github*/** node_modules** node_modules*/** resources/js** resources/js*/** resources/css** resources/css*/** resources/sass* resources/sass*/** Workspace* Workspace*/** .vscode* .vscode*/** .gitignore* .gitignore*/**  .gitattributes* .gitattributes*/**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with github website.

 github's action's status turned incident!

i should've checked out [github](https://www.githubstatus.com/) status page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
exclude: '
    - **/vendor/**
    - **/vendor*/**
    - **/node_modules/**
    - **/node_modules*/**
    - **/resource/css/**
    - **/resource/css*/**
    - **/resource/js/**
    - **/resource/js*/**
    - **/.git/**
    - **/.git*/**
    '
```